# Why does $\int_C\frac{dz}{z}=2\pi i$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I was thinking that I don't really understand why
$$\int_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{z}=2\pi i$$

I do understand how to calculate it and it's importance for residues, Cauchy etc... The question is that, if $f(z)=z^{-1}$, then $f(z)=\overline{z}$ when $|z|=1$, somehow there must be an asymmetry in $f(z)$ along $|z|=1$ in order for the integral to be $2\pi$ units up in the imaginary axis. If $C$ is the unit circle traversed in the natural (anticlockwise) direction at "1 m/s speed"(i.e. $e^{i\theta}$ for $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$) then $f(C)$ is again the unit circle traversed at "1 m/s" speed but in a clockwise manner. Then again, I don't see any asymmetry: you will pass both by $z$ and $-z$ and those should cancel giving $0$ as the value of the integral.

I tried to think of the line integral in terms of area: $ie^{i\theta}$ is the tangent vector to the curve at $z=e^{i\theta}$ and an infinitesimal triangle (or circle sector) should have area $\frac{1}{2}ie^{i\theta}e^{i\theta}$. Couldn't get any further because what meaning does "complex number value area" mean? Is there some interpretation? I am not convinced that the $\gamma'(t)$ factor appearing in the calculations really makes the difference (or how it would).
Just to add to my controversy, the function $f(z)=z^{-2}$ takes the unit circle into the unit circle but "changes speeds" by which I mean that it gives somehow "more weight" to some points (it stretches the upper semicircle into the whole circle)

Maybe the question sounds stupid and I hope it does have a simple explanation.

Thanks!

Comment: As we traverse the circle anticlockwise, $1/z$ will traverse the circle clockwise and their contributions are proportional, and cancel out and we are left with the direction $i$, which is integrated over the circle, which has length $2\pi$, so we get $2\pi i$. Formally, this corresponds to $\int_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{z}=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{e^{it}}ie^{it}=\int_0^{2\pi}i=2\pi i$. I'm sure there's more to be said, though.

Comment: @rtybase I'm afraid not. I already know all the theorems and proofs and calculations behind. I was looking for something on the lines of the only posted answer (as of now) which (I think) I'll accept when I find the time to read it carefully. Of course I welcome any "non computational" answer. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first argument applies to a related, but different integral, where we really do sum up the values of $f(e^{i\theta})$ over time and find a cancellation between 
$z$ and $-z$:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(e^{i\theta})\,d\theta = 0.$$
Note, however, that this integral is not of the desired form: the argument $e^{i\theta}$ to the function $f$ is different from the variable we are integrating with $\theta$. The intuition behind this integral is taking an "average" of $\frac{1}z$ over the unit circle, but line integrals are up to something else: they are better thought of as measuring something more like the physical quantity of "how much energy does one gain when pushing an object counterclockwise around the circle against a force acting clockwise?" rather than "at a random angle, what is the expectation of my position?" - and note that this is captured in the notation, since the above integral mentions the *angle*, whereas the integral $\int_C f(z)\,dz$ mentions only the position - and hence is resistant to reparameterization.

To be more precise, if $g:\mathbb C\rightarrow \mathbb C$ is thought of as a field of forces at each point, then
$$\operatorname{Re}\left(\int_C\overline{g(z)}\,dz\right)$$
is the energy gained by a point along the curve $C$ in the field $g$. If we set $g(z)=\overline{f(z)}$ to relate this case to the given one, we would see that $g(z)=z$ on the circle $C$, so the force would always be perpendicular to the motion - hence the real part of the given integral is $0$. However, if we want the *imaginary* part of this integral, we would see that that's the real part of $\int_C \overline{ig(z)}\,dz$ and we would note that the field $ig(z)$ is circulating counterclockwise - hence would always push the point along its direction of motion, thus leading to an increase in energy, the same way that dropping a ball in a constant field of gravity leads to an increase of energy as it falls in the same direction as the force acting on it. Note also that $\int_{|z|=1}$ is not such a good notation, because the physical intuition makes it clear that it matters a lot which *way* we go (since going counterclockwise, the force helps us along, and going clockwise, it hinders us) and how many times we go around.

We can also just look at this integral formally; we have
$$\int_C \frac{dz}z$$
and if we substitute $z=e^{i\theta}$ which implies $dz=ie^{i\theta}\,d\theta$ we get
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{ie^{i\theta}}{e^{i\theta}}=\int_{0}^{2\pi}i\,d\theta = 2\pi i$$
where we see that the direction in which $z$ is moving cancels, by multiplication, with the value of the function at that $z$. Note that this converts line integrals into the integral of a function from $\mathbb R$ and if we applied this process to $z^{-2}$, we would get the first integral in this post as a result - and, physically, the field given by $\overline{z^{-2}}$ would constantly change its angle to the unit circle over a rotation, hence would not create any energy.

The reason for this is largely the same as why one has $d\theta$ in the real case: the value $f(z)\,dz$ means that the amount of value this term contributes to the integral is the change in $z$ over a small interval times $f(z)$ - that's essentially what Riemann integration formalizes. For complex numbers, the change in $z$ is likely not real, but the value $f(z)$ is sort a hypothetical saying "if $z$ increased by $1$ and the value of the function stayed the same, how much would that segment contribute to the integral?" and if $z$ is moving in some other direction, we have to compensate for that. Essentially*, you can think of the term $f(z)\,dz$ as defining, at each point $z$, a linear function $\mathbb C\rightarrow\mathbb C$ taking "small changes in $z$" to "small changes in the integral" and the term $\frac{dz}z$ just happens to define the function that takes the clockwise tangent to the unit circle to $i$ at all points on the unit circle.

---

Perhaps another useful example to consider is integrating the constant $1$ around the unit circle; obviously, if we set $f(z)=1$ then $\int_C f(e^{i\theta})\,d\theta = 2\pi$, which reflects that the average value of $f$ is $1$ along the unit circle. Since the term $1\,dz$ represents that a change in $z$ is reflected exactly as a change in the integrated value, the integral
$$\int_C 1\,dz$$ 
represents summing up all of the changes in $z$ over a circle - but since the changes in $z$ are not weighted in any way, this integral is just equal to the total change in $z$ over the curve $C$ - which is $0$ for any closed loop.

---

One last note which is maybe less explanatory than the others, but is a nice idea that forces ones intuition about everything else into place: really, an integral $\int f(z)\,dz$ is trying to find an antiderivative $F$ of $f$. So, we're essentially stuck only with the rule that $F(z)=f(z)$. This tells us why we have to define the integral the way we did: $f(z)$ is literally the ratio $\frac{F(z+h)-F(z)}{h}$ meaning that $F(z+h)\approx F(z) + h f(z)$, where $h$ is some small change - so this term $h f(z)$ tells us how quickly the antiderivative changes when we move with a velocity of $h$.

If $f$ is defined on a disk (or any simply connected open set), then we can even *define* an anti-derivative $F$ by choosing a base point $x_0$ and setting $F(z)$ to be the line integral of $f$ along any path from $x_0$ to $z$ - where the choice of path provably will not matter. More strongly, if every integral along a loop works out to zero, this definition gives an antiderivative (...which is a named theorem, but I forget the name). When the integrals over loops fail to come out to $0$, we know that there's some problem in defining an anti-derivative. For $f(z)=1/z$ the issue is that we would like $F(z)=\log(z)$, but the logarithm isn't well defined because $e^{0}=e^{2\pi i}$ - so exponentiation is not invertible. The integral $\int\frac{dz}z$ then can be thought of as considering what happens if we look at the curve $e^{i\theta}$ and try to find a function $h(\theta)$ so that $e^{i\theta}=e^{h(\theta)}$. If we insist that $h$ be continuous, we find out that $h(2\pi) - h(0)$ must be $2\pi i$ - which tells us exactly *how* $1/z$ fails to have an antiderivative and how $e^z$ fails to have an inverse.

---

*This is *exactly* what a differential form is defined to be, in the somewhat trivial case where we are studying $\mathbb C$. We just don't think about it too much because the only linear functions $\mathbb C\rightarrow\mathbb C$ are those that just multiply their input by some constant.